# Obter a URL anterior com javascript

Tags: javascript

Como faço para obter a URL anterior da página atual em javascript?

Comment: Pra pegar a url anterior, basta usar `document.referrer`. Pra voltar a página anterior, basta usar `history.back()`

Answer (score 9):

```
document.referrer
```

[De acordo com a MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document.referrer) em tradução minha mesmo;

> Retorna a URI da página que fez o link. Retorna uma string vazia se o usuário navegou para a página diretamente (não através de um link, por exemplo, através de um *bookmark*). Como esta propriedade retorna uma string ela não te da acesso a DOM a página referida

Esta propriedade [está na especificação da DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140) portanto é esperado que seja *cross browser*, entretanto você pode testar se o browser a implementa dessa forma;

```
if( typeof document['referrer'] !== 'undefined' ) { 
    //Seu browser suporta document.referrer
}
```

**Observação:** Algumas versões do IE nem sempre definem esta propriedade; [veja esta thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724869/document-referrer-indexof-breaking-in-ie8) (em inglês)

**Observação 2:** Talvez você pode estar interessado em se preocupar com segurança anti-XSS ao usar `document.referrer`, [é uma questão já levantada por outros](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66217/how-can-document-referrer-be-used-for-xss) (também em inglês).